# string text to many linkbuttons (asp.net c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, linkbutton

I am retrieving data from table column where I have saved tags for the article, for **example:** `"animals dogs cats"` and showing this string text in `linkbutton`. If I click it, then page is redirected to `"Tags.aspx?name=animals dogs cats"`.

Is it possible to redirect page to `"Tags.aspx?name=cats"` 
if I have clicked on "cats", or maybe to split the string and show each word in own `linkbutton` (without using something like `listview`)?

Thanks, Oak

Comment: have you tried to creata a button for each tag in your code? you can split the string and create a new button for each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use a web-databound control like `Repeater` you can create the `LinkButton`s dynamically. Remember to recreate them on postbacks with the same ID as before in `Page_Load` at the latest:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    createTagButtons();
}

private void createTagButtons()
{ 
    var tblTags = new DataTable();
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TagID, TagName FROM dbo.Tags ORDER BY TagName", con))
    {
        da.Fill(tblTags);
    }

    foreach (DataRow row in tblTags.Rows)
    {
        int tagID =  row.Field<int>("TagID");
        string tagName = row.Field<string>("TagName");
        LinkButton tagButton = new LinkButton();
        tagButton.ID = "tagButton_" + tagID;
        tagButton.CommandArgument = tagName;
        tagButton.Click += TagLinkClicked;
        this.TagPanel.Controls.Add(tagButton);
    }
}

private void TagLinkClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton tagLink = (LinkButton)sender;
    string url = string.Format("Tags.aspx?name={0}", tagLink.CommandArgument);
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

On the aspx you could use a `Panel`:

```
<asp:Panel ID="TagPanel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

Comment: I think, i can use this idea for my needs. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string[] words = your_string.Split();` and then create buttons using loop

Comment: Could you tell me how to create these buttons in correct location, because now i have placed that linkbutton between other controls and im using "Eval" to show the text?

Answer (score 0):

A link will show only one view called from the controller.
That is, if you have a tag "cat" and this tag is related with some view then this tag calls that view which is written in the controller.

Comment: His view is called Tags, so "cat", "dog" and etc. - are just parameters